# Java environmental variable woes, maven also

Tags: java, maven-2, windows-7, environment-variables

So I re-installed java in a directory that doesn't have any spaces in it, as I was having issues with it before.

Java JDK is installed in:

```
E:\downloads\java\jdk
```

I created a User variable:

```
JAVA_HOME E:\downloads\java\jdk
```

And my Path looks like:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%;
```

Now opening a **NEW** cmd prompt:

```
c:\java
'java' is not recognized...
```

but echoing works:

```
c:\echo %JAVA_HOME%
E:\downloads\java\jdk
```

and so does this:

```
c:\%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
```

I am trying to get this to work, so I can then get maven to work as maven is having the same type of issues (I created M2_HOME and M2 and none work).

**What exactly am I doing wrong?  I am having the exact same issue on my laptop also, both are running windows 7.  I must be missing something!**

**Edit**
As per your comments, the output of M2 is:

set M2
M2=E:\downloads\java\apache-maven-2.2.1-bin\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin
M2_HOME: e:\downloads\java\apache-maven-2.2.1-bin\apache-maven-2.2.1

set PATH

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/6996/javasetpath.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/6996/javasetpath.png)

Comment: Execute Path Command at CMD and send me what do you see?

Comment: Show the output of `set PATH` (and also `set M2`)

Comment: @Pascal I took a screenshot for your, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see on your capture, `%JAVA_HOME%` and `%M2%` are not expanded in your `PATH`. I suspect that you mixed  *User variables* and *System variables*. Declare PATH as a ***User variable*** like this:

```
%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: yes that works, but I don't understand.  Does it pull the system variable PATH into my user variable, so then all sessions have access to the PATH?  confused why it worked...

Comment: @Blankman User variables "see" system variables but the other way around is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Try to append a slash ('\') at the end of the path, like this:

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;%M2%;`

and let me know if it worked.

Comment: nope it didn't, and yes I opened a new cmd prompt :) thanks thought!